# Intellij IDEA: java file marked as "excluded from compilation"

Tags: intellij-idea

I run across a strange issue:

the file marked by the cross is excluded from compilation.

Does anybody know about this and what to do to get rid of that?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There was the entry at this path:

`Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Excludes`

I've just removed this (wrongly inserted) entry